# No encuentra recursos (javascript, css) al desplegar proyecto en IIS

Tags: c#, iis

Me gustaría preguntar acerca de un problema que he estado experimentando con IIS.

Digamos que despliego mi sitio en `C:wwwRoot / MyProjectName / (todos los archivos de sitio aquí )` . El despliegue parece funcionar sin ningún problema .

Entonces cuando voy al navegador e intento `http : //MyServerIp/MyProjectName/index.html`, el sitio de inicio comienza la carga , pero cuando verifico la consola del chrome todos los recursos incluidos en index.html ( CSS , JS ) , lanzan un error diciendo que:

> Http : //MyServerIp/SomeFile.js experimento un error al tratar de
>   conseguir el recurso, porque el archivo no se pudo encontrar .

Por supuesto, el problema es debido a que el sitio debe estar buscando estos archivos en : `http : //MyServerIp/MyProjectName/SomeFile.js` .

Así que por alguna razón IIS esta eliminando de la ruta el : MyProjectName .

El sitio es un sitio basado en C# con AngularJS .

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola!!! este es un sitio de P&R en español.. y si reformulas la pregunta en español?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta en ingles

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos escenarios con los cuales la solución varía, estos son o tu sitio está publicado como *Aplicación web*  sobre un sitio web o está publicado como *sitio web* y solo es una *subcarpeta*. La diferencia es que al referenciar la raiz de tu aplicación se podría interpretar de manera diferente.

Cuando estás trabajando con una **aplicación web** ya sea de web forms o mvc puedes usar la ruta `"~/"` para referenciar la *raiz de tu aplicación* que en este caso es **`http://tuservidoroip/tuaplicacion`**. Pero, cuando estés trabajando con una subcarpeta de un sitio estó no funcionará. Esta manera de referenciar la raiz de la aplicación solo funciona cuando tu documento HTML pasa por algún procesamiento de ASP y éste es el que reeescribe las rutas. Así que no estás seguro, opta por la siguiente opción. Ejemplo:

```html
<script src='@Url.Content("~/path/tuscript.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Cuando estás trabajando con una **subcarpeta** dentro de un sitio puedes optar por hacer una redirección desde la raiz de tu sevidor utilizando el carácter `"/"`. Ejemplo:

```html
<script src="/tuservidor/tuproyecto/path/tuscrip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**NOTA:** Cuando utilizas el carácter `'~'` y no estás haciendo que ASP te procese esta dirección (Por ejemplo no usar el método Url.Content) el sistema escribirá tal cual la url y te seguirá dando problema, así que solo utilizalo cuando estés seguro de que ASP lo procesa antes.

Answer (score 0):

agrega tus recursos de esta manera:

Javascripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fonts.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Saludos